# how to get the current day of week in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, windows-forms-designer

I declared a variable named `date` with type `DateTime` in Visual Studio 2017 but when I try to access `DateTime::DayOfWeek`, I cannot do so. I was trying to give `date` that value like this

```
    DateTime dayy;
    dayy = DateTime::DayOfWeek;
```

But I get error

> A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Comment: What is `DateTime::DayOfWeek`? Is it a non-static member variable? What would its value be? Perhaps you should take a few steps back, [get a few good books to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and start over?

Comment: I'm confused, is this C++ or C#? `DateTime` is a .NET thing.

Comment: I am using C++ in Visual Studio @acraig5075 windows forms

Comment: Are you perhaps using [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI)? Then please edit your question to correct the tags.

Comment: Try `DateTime.DayOfWeek` that's the .NET way of accessing a property, but I'm just guessing because I'm still confused as to how you're doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use time.h

```
#include <time.h>

time_t timeObj = time(nullptr);
tm aTime;
localtime_s(&aTime, &timeObj);
std::cout << aTime.tm_wday;
```